# Inserting data into table via stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I created a table and stored procedures to insert data into table via GUI on reportnet but data is not being inserted so I came back to check if there is any error in my insert stored procedure.

I tried to execute the stored procedure as

```
EXEC DBO.Tablename 'param1','Param2'
```

etc. I don't know if I executed it correctly, but it errors out as one more column should be supplied. Could someone help me how to execute the stored procedure to insert values?

This is the code I used to create the stored procedure:

```
Create Procedure dbo.abc_insert  
       @queryaction Varchar(6),
       @a varchar(8),
       @b varchar(16),
       @c varchar(8),
       @d varchar(16),
       @e varchar(8),
       @f DATETIME(16)  

    Declare @g DATETIME,
            @Msg Varchar(max),  

    -- Variable initialization
    select @g=processdate from util.dbo.processdate

    -- validate @queryaction
    IF @queryaction not in ('insert','delete') or @a is null
    begin
        set @msg='error'
        Raiserror (@msg,18,1);
        return
    end

    --INSERT
    if @queryaction ='insert'
        insert into dbo.abc_insert (a, b, c, d, e, f, g)
        values (@a, @b, @c, @d, @e, @f, @g)
```

I'm trying to execute this query and check if its working at first place to see any coding errors.

I tried to execute like this:

```
EXEC dbo.abc_insert 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' 
--(g value will be taken from  process date so not entering g value)
```

When executing this is, this error occurs:

> procedure or function abc_insert expects parameter @f, which was not supplied.

Comment: Please show us what you have already done and then somebody from the community will be able to help you out.

Comment: Can you share the code please?

Comment: I hope i made some sense now

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass all the required parameters - that's `@queryaction` first, followed by six values. You currently *only* send in the six values - but nothing for query action:

```
EXEC dbo.abc_insert 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
```

You need to provide that `@queryaction` value, too!

```
EXEC dbo.abc_insert 'insert', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Variable `@f DATETIME(16)` is wrong type,

should is quite simply `@f DATETIME`

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @dt as datetime = getdate() 
EXEC    abc_insert 'insert', 'a','b', 'c','d','e',@dt
```

Note: @f DATETIME(16)  should be @f DATETIME in your create script